# How can I limit requests per minute on a web server (Flask)

Tags: flask, ddos

I want to make an anti-ddos. I want to make it so if more than 45 requests are made in one minute, the ip that requested that will be ip-blacklisted for 30 minutes.

How can I do this with flask, no db

Comment: You can’t prevent a DDOS attack. This is just rate limiting the endpoints.

Comment: ah so you want that one single person in a large company / dormitory / university / complete country behind a NAT router / Wifi access point + DSL model / Carrier-grade NAT can block all 1000 / 2000 / 10000 / 1000000 users? Because, that would sound like that single person can deny all the others your service by making 46 requests.

Comment: @jwu Dude, the whole company / dormitory / university / country has one single external IP address. Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT

Comment: @MarcusMüller Dude, I know but for my type of service, I don't think like universites will use it

Comment: @Shivam Well then how can I do that?

Comment: i.e. what you're proposing has nothing to do with DDOS, but is simply IP-based rate limiting. It doesn't help against DDOSing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know what DDOS means, and even if it has nothing to do with ddos, I still wan't to know how to do "IP-based rate limiting"

Comment: @jwu Use a service like [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com)

Comment: Is there any other way, like through flask?

Comment: @jwu then please edit your question to make clear you don't want DDOS protection, but rate-limiting; as it is, the text of your question contradicts its title.

Comment: I don’t think you know how DDOS works. You need to stop the bad requests before they get to the web server.

Comment: You could also use nginx for rate limiting...

Comment: Flask server on port 8080 for example and reverse proxy with nginx. I know rate limiting won't help very much against an ddos attack but if your project needs a lot of performance loading then nginx would be an good free alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't recommend only rate-limiting it just won't help you if the attacker is using proxies and can set the requests per second for every Proxy. I would recommend using Cloudflare with challenges (js challenges) you can also rate Limit your requests there for 0.05$ every 10000 legit requests.

Answer (score 3):

If you want DDOS protection, use a service like [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com). Rate-limiting won’t help stop DDOS.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

The very basic answer and solution to rate-limiting is by using the following
Flask Library https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ known as `flask-limiter` . It can go ahead and provide us with proper rate-limiting features at an application level. But be aware that using this for protecting against DDoS Attacks or even some simple DOS (Denial of Service) attacks would not be mitigated  with a nice proxy list on the end of the attacker.

### Proper Solution & Easier (Using Cloudflared)

1. Download and Install the `cloudflared.deb`
   using `sudo dpkg -i cloudflared-ver_xxx.deb`
2. Configure and create an Argo Tunnel as Provided by Cloudflare Docs.
3. Access the Domain or Subdomain of your Application using the Argo Tunnel.

### Example

In my case if I have an application locally running for `localhost:1909`.
And using proper forwarding in my `config.yaml` (please refer Cloudflare Docs to configure), I can access it on lets say `myapp.example.com` or `www.example.com`

#### Advantages

1. Automatic HTTPS Certificate and Redirection.
2. Faster and More Better and Easier to Configure.
3. SEO now requires HTTPS Certificates for better rating (you can derive).

Answer (score 0):

IP-based Rate limiting:

Sure, it's not actually hard: just have a dict with an entry (key) for each IP address that uses your service; in that dict, each value is a list of the (at most) last 45 times that IP address accessed. When the list actually reaches a length of 45, you check whether the last entry is actually within the last hour - and if so, you just block (whatever that means).

You need to regularly scrub that dict from keys whose first list entry is older than an hour, otherwise it will eat up your RAM.

By the way, do you know what software is called that keeps a table in check and can give you answers to questions like "what's the last entry for that key?"?
That's a database. Your problem is requiring a database-alike thing.

Comment: Yeah I know what a database is

Comment: yes, but the point is the problem you're describing actually describes a database, yet you define that a database is not the solution. my remark was intended to point out that you might have a bit of a misunderstanding how complex a database needs to be. Not everything needs a MariaSQL cluster! For your application, a simple SQLite instance would fully do.